# OAuth2 for existing Camel REST Endpoints

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, apache-camel

We are trying to implement OAuth2 to a few of our existing REST endpoints without rewriting them. The REST API is implemented in Camel. I am looking for a simple and easy way to do this.

I have tried [OAuth2 with JAZ- RS](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-oauth.html)  but wasn't much help. The initial use case for the OAuth2 is very simple, we will have a new client trying to hit our REST API and we need to validate the client (yes or no).

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a reverse proxy in front of your REST endpoints and have that proxy handle the OAuth 2.0 dance. See e.g. https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc.